# Android NullPointer Exception in method kpg.initializate

Tags: java, android, security, rsa

I'm a newbie in android and I'm trying to make a "simple" tutorial about a cypher/decypher application. I've the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg;
    KeyPair kp;
    PublicKey publicKey;
    PrivateKey privateKey;
    byte[] encryptedBytes, decryptedBytes;
    Cipher cipher, cipher1;
    String encrypted, decrypted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            generateKey();
            TextView txtPuk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewPUK);
            txtPuk.setText(kp.getPublic().toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException,BadPaddingException,InvalidKeyException{
        try{
                kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(1024); //NULLPOINTER HERE
            kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
    public byte[] RSAEncrypt(final String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        ;
        publicKey = kp.getPublic();
        privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public String RSADecrypt(final byte[] encryptedBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        decryptedBytes = cipher1.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
        decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);
        return decrypted;
    }

}
```

But as the title says, I get a NullPointer in `kpg.initialize(1024)`.
Since the theory seems to be correct, I feel that this may be a blind trick that I'm not following, so what may be the reason for this to happen

EDIT: Edited code to remove redudant code, like sugested

Comment: Try moving `kpg.initialize(1024);  kp = kpg.genKeyPair();` to the previous try catch block.

Comment: sorry I made those two try/block in order to find out which one was giving the null pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is calling `findViewById(R.id.tViewPUK)` before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Comment: Right on the pocket :^)